# GameObject is deformed when HandGrabing

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

(I'm developing for first time in unity/ VR)
I am using the Oculus Interaction SDK in my unity project.

In Runntime when I try to grab a Gameobject (made with two cubes) it deforms.
I have a *Grabbable* and *Hand Grab Interactable* components
I coundn't be able to solve that and hope anyone here knows what to fix that..

I tried all the possibilites in Inspector! also to make a Box collider for the Gameobject(eventhought there are already two for the cubes)